# SleekXMPP request presence for specific user?

Tags: python, xmpp, chat

I can't find this in any of the examples or docs.

I'm using an MUC bot. When a user logs in the presence data is saved to a global dict. That dict is used in the message handler to get user information.

In the message handler if a user is not in the dict of profiles I would like to request it specifically. Is this possible without probing the presence data of the entire userlist? I just want to check if user exists in dict and if not, requests presence data from server for that individual user.

Comment: In what case are you thinking a user would be online and not in the dict already?

Comment: @MattJ Every once in a while it seems to happen. Not sure if it's a network hiccup or a server issue. It seems to be a problem with the web client (Candy Chat) as well where sometimes a talking user will not be in the client's user list. I can see it in my script where upon user logoff I'll get a keyerror exception that they don't exist in the dict when the script tries to remove them.